# How can I train a neural network for another input set, without losing the learning of the previous input set?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, artificial-neuron, sigmoid

I read [this tutorial](https://hmkcode.com/ai/backpropagation-step-by-step/) about backpropagation.

So using this backpropagation we are training the neural network repeatedly for one input set, say [2,4], until we reach 100% accuracy of getting 1 as output. And the neural network is adjusting its weight values accordingly. So once after the neural network is trained this way, suppose we are giving another input set, say [6,8], also then will the neural network update its weight values (overwriting previous values), right? This will result in losing the previous learning, right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is actually a limitation known as [catastrophic forgetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference). 
A proposed way to deal with this is elastic weight consolidation that "remembers old tasks by selectively slowing down learning on the weights important for those tasks". See [Overcoming catastrophic forgetting in neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00796) for details. Another approach is [Learning without forgetting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.09282.pdf).

If the tasks are different, the approach you are talking about is called transfer learning. You might want to have a look at multi-task learning as well

If the tasks are the same, you could try creating a join of both datasets and training on that.